# Swift to Objective C Conversion

Tags: objective-c, swift, type-conversion

Converting a project from Swift to Objective C

Please help what will be this swift line of code in objective c

```
let corners: UIRectCorner =  UIRectCorner.TopRight.union(.BottomRight)
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please post what have you tried so far and take a look at how to ask good questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
   UIRectCorner corners=UIRectCornerTopRight|UIRectCornerBottomRight;
```

Comment: can you please tell why some guys voting down my question. what is wrong in it.

Comment: I didnt downvote ur question but, your question doesn't show any effort. It simply asks for the answer. You need to show what you tried, and what is the issue , then no one will downvote ur quesiton.